# Qt Hiding the console window stop writing the log file

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a Qt project. If I start my application using Qt Creator, I never seen any console window.(But the exe will be seen in the task manager).

But if i run the application exe directly, a console window is popping up and closing also.

I hide the console window by removing the `CONFIG   += console` from the **project.pro** file. But this change the affecting the `qDebug()` logging. ie, nothing is added to the log file (okb file).

Development environent: Qt 4.7.3/Windows

Comment: What is an "okb" file and what are you doing to get qDebug() output into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no console window, all debug output is sent to [debugger](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/debug.html) using `OutputDebugString`. I.e. you can read it from debugger (visual studio express - "output" window using debugger), but you can't redirect it to file by running something like `app > 1.txt` (because application without console technically has no stdout).

Alternatively, you could install your own message handler for debugging message using [qInstallMsgHandler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) and write your own logfile however you want.

Comment: I tried implementing qInstallMsgHandler, but its working only if I enable console window.

Comment: @JChan: " but its working only if" Which simply means you've implemented it incorrectly. You can't simply use std::cout or printf in non-console windows application, even if you use qInstallMsgHandler. Open logfile, and write into that logfile from message handler.

Comment: implementation was wrong, its working thanks..